# Build failed after TeamCity agent shutdown

Tags: teamcity

We have TeamCity with several agents and some agents run on employee's/programmers computer. If the employee shutdown computer in the evening, the running build is mark as failed and email notification is sent. Is is possible in the case of shutdown, to mark the build as cancelled and choose different agent and run the build again on different agent?

Comment: simple solution - dont run TeamCity builds on people's laptops. altering the build history isnt a good idea .. there is no need to find workarounds for bad practices

Comment: We run not only build, even some quality test, which runs for hours. We don't have enough enough unoccupied servers to use, but we have plenty of user stations.

Comment: In book "How we test in Microsoft", you can read that even Microsoft run test on user stations. But I am not sue, if they switch it off.

Comment: its a common practice that before the developer pushed the code he will run all the tests locally on his station, but the build system isnt supposed to have nodes on developers stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if the computer is shutdown while TeamCity build is running, it [build] will be marked as failed anyway. So the question is how to rerun build after failure on new machine.

You can create agent pools and assign several build agents to the pool. After that you should edit 'Agent requirements' setting in build configuration, so your build can be run on any alive machine.

You can use 'Retry build trigger' in trigger sections to rerun your build after failure. It will rerun all failed builds, but it is OK for your problem

Comment: In my point of view is bad, if he build is mark as failed. Because it will be visible in history as failed. Unless it will be somehow automatically deleted and add to build queue again.

Comment: We use build pools, but it does not solve the problem with marking build as false. Retry builder trigger is a good idea, that solve returning a build to queue. Then the thing to be solved is to delete the interrupted build from results.

Comment: You can use TC REST API to list failed builds and delete builds: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests so you can easily automate it.

Comment: I tested it again and it appears that if the retry trigger is specified, that the Email notification is not sent after the first failure, which is exactly what I need and thus finally I don't need to remove canceled build. The only think what I don't like is that the retry trigger is launched even if some unittest do not pass and I am not able to detect a code with random behavior (threading). Unfortunately there is no preset "retry if cancelled trigger".Is there some solution for "retry if cancelled trigger"? I have found "Custom Build Trigger" which can be programmed,this could be solution.

Answer (score 1):

Build retry trigger (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Triggers) + TC REST API (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests) to delete failed builds.

Comment: You right, I tried to run build, turn off computer and the build was marked as cancelled. That is exactly what the rest API do. It appears that if the retry trigger is specify, that the email notification is not sent after the first failure, which is exactly what I need and thus finally I don't need to to remove canceled build. For more please see comment of boosha bellow.

Comment: I didn't know that with retry trigger, when build fails it doesn't send email. That's interesting, I will check it :)